# Java installer temporarily deployed by Inno Setup is included in installation size

Tags: inno-setup

```
[Files]
#define JavaInstaller "jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe"
Source: "{#JavaInstaller}";  DestDir: "{tmp}"; 

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}/{#JavaInstaller}"; Parameters: "SPONSORS=0"; \
   StatusMsg: "Java Runtime Enviroment not installed on your system. Installing..."; \
   Check: not isJavaInstalled
```

```pascal
[Code]
const
  REQUIRED_JAVA_VERSION = '1.7';

function isJavaInstalled(): Boolean;
var
  JavaVer : String;
  tmpFileName,
  pathJavaExe: String;
  isGoodJavaVersion,
  isFoundJavaPath: Boolean;
  ResultCode: Integer;
  ExecStdout: AnsiString;
begin

  { *** check in registry }
  { sets variables: }
  {   JavaVer }
  {   isGoodJavaVersion }
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment',
           'CurrentVersion', JavaVer) AND (JavaVer <> '') OR
     RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment',
           'CurrentVersion', JavaVer) AND (JavaVer <> '') then begin
    Log('* Java Entry in Registry present. Version: ' + JavaVer);
    isGoodJavaVersion := CompareStr(JavaVer, REQUIRED_JAVA_VERSION) >= 0;
  end;

  { add additional checks, for example by searching the PATH, }
  { or by running `java -version` }

  Result := isGoodJavaVersion;
end;
```

I am a beginner using Inno Setup. I am trying to use the above code to make an installer for "MyProgram".

As part of the installation the installer needs to check if Java is installed and if not to install it.

The problem I am having is that the installer installs "MyProgram" but it also installs "jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe" as part of "MyProgram".

So instead of the installation of "MyProgram" being around 10Mb it is 75mB. From what I have read sources loaded to "{tmp} should uninstall automatically once the exe has run, but in this case it does not seem to happen.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. 1) do you mean that after the installation finishes, the `jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe` remains in `{tmp}`? 2) Or is your problem that installer (`mysetup.exe`) is too large (as it contains `jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe`)?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean that even if java is installed the jre-8u151-windows-x64.ex is part of the installation on my local machine.This happens if Java is installed or not on the local machine.

Comment: Sorry, but that's as ambiguous as before. What do you mean by *"part of the installation on my local machine"*? Be more specific. Where/how does the `jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe` become *part of the installation*?

Comment: if I take out this line "{#JavaInstaller}";  DestDir: "{tmp}"; then when MyProgam installs and is only around 8Mb. But if I include that line, MyProgram install and is 75Mb which I think is due to the Java Installer being installed as part of the MyProgram install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean, that the `jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe` is included into `EstimatedSize` field of the program unininstall entry. It does not actually occupy any space on the disk. Right?

This [was a bug in Inno Setup](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/4172649490dd3b3439ed6871b08747c714bb67ee). It was fixed in Inno Setup 5.6.

---

In earlier version, to workaround the bug, you can extract the installer programmatically using [`ExtractTemporaryFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile), instead of using the `[Files]` section.

```
[Files]
Source: "{#JavaInstaller}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}/{#JavaInstaller}"; Parameters: "SPONSORS=0"; \
    StatusMsg: "Java Runtime Environment not installed on your system. Installing..."; \
    Check: not isJavaInstalled; BeforeInstall: ExtractInstaller
```

```pascal
[Code]

function isJavaInstalled(): Boolean;
begin
  { ... }
end;

procedure ExtractInstaller;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('{#JavaInstaller}');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it all seemed to be working but then comes up with an error message "Exception internal error: ExtractTemporaryFile: The file "jre-8u151-windows-64.exe was not found.

Comment: Do you have the `Source: "{#JavaInstaller}"; Flags: dontcopy` entry?

Comment: I've changed it so that in the next version this is fixed. Thanks for your report.